# Is there a way to use stringWithFormat: to leave out null parts?

Tags: objective-c, string, cocoa-touch, stringwithformat

In my iOS app, I need to do some string formatting after being passed in a set of parameters and a format.

For example: `%@\n%@\n%@, %@ %@` with params `line1`, `line2`, `city`, `state`, `zip`] would become:

line1
line2
city, state zip

Is there a way to omit the second `%@\n` if `line2` is `nil`?

If it can't be done this way, is there another way to do it?

Answer (score 4):

Pre-format `line2`, making it an empty string if it is `nil`:

```
line2 = line2 ? [line2 stringByAppendingString:@"\n"] : @"";
NSString * address = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\n%@%@, %@ %@", line1, line2, city, state, zip];
```

Comment: Is there a more generic way of doing it? If I had a different format passed in, and any of them could be blank would I have to do the preformat on every parameter to check?

Comment: You're going to have to do some creative/clever formatting no matter what.

Comment: @cain That's why you get paid the big $$ .. to tell the computer how to behave with the data it's given

Comment: Trying to make this completely generic will get out of hand really fast, @cain. In particular, there's no super-simple way to conditionally put newlines in between certain arguments. You can construct a string that ignores `nil` strings pretty easily by appending instead of using `stringWithFormat:`, though.

Comment: @JoshCaswell, yeah, I was afraid of that.  I think that instead of a format string, I will have to pass a set of formatting options for each param depending on whether or not the param is blank or not.